# Time series data modelling in python

Tags: python, data-science

I have a data set in which date(yyyy/mm/dd), hour and output are the three columns. Can i model this data as a time series data to forecast the output as a function of the date and hour using ARIMA or any other algorithm?

Comment: in short - yes. What exactly is the challenge that you are trying to address here?

Comment: i am pretty new to Data science and M L and i am unable to understand how to model this data as an ARIMA model because ARIMA is univariate. Since i have output as a function of two variables here i dont know how to model it in python. it would be great if you can tell me how to do this in python. Thanks!

Comment: you need to combine date and time columns into single one with `datetime` format. See example in the answer. Accept if it helps.

Comment: Please, provide a minimum Minimal, Reproducible Example:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example. It assumes the data is imported into pandas dataframe. I presume that you are familiar with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'date': "2019/12/29", 'hour': 12, 'output': 42},
        {'date': "2019/12/30", 'hour': 10, 'output': 36},
        {'date': "2019/12/31", 'hour': 23, 'output': 48}]
df=pd.DataFrame(data)  # build DataFrame (do this with your data).

df['time'] = df.date + ' ' + df.hour.astype(str)  # create date+time string
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format='%Y/%m/%d %H') # convert to datetime format

print(df)
         date  hour  output                time
0  2019/12/29    12      42 2019-12-29 12:00:00
1  2019/12/30    10      36 2019-12-30 10:00:00
2  2019/12/31    23      48 2019-12-31 23:00:00
```

as a result you will have time labels in `datetime` format, ready for further analysis.